# How do I change my password on ebay?

Tags: account-management, passwords, ebay

Where in the maze of configuration settings is this located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Login to eBay
2. Click the personal menu in the top left. (It says something like "Hi Justin!")
3. Click the "Account settings" link
4. On the "Account" tab, click the "Personal information" link on the left side
5. In the account information section, click the edit button on the row that is for your password

Comment: The eBay interface has changed a lot since Phil originally posted this. In light of eBay's recent breach, I've updated this post to be more accurate.